# Excel VBA assigning values to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having issue assigning values to an array.  Getting an out of range error when trying to assign

What I'm trying to do is loop through the rows in a table and assign certain values to load a listbox.

I've been using this:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("B1:C" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
With Me.lbWaste
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count
    '~~> create a one based 2-dim datafield array
     myArray = rng
    '~~> fill listbox with array values
    .List = myArray
    '~~> Set the widths of the column here. Ex: For 5 Columns
    '~~> Change as Applicable
    .ColumnWidths = "100;50;50"
    .TopIndex = 0
End With
```

but since it just copy and pastes the range values, there's hidden rows included in the data returned.

the columns I'm trying to copy to an array are b and c

how would I assign data to array using

```
for each rng in workbook1.sheets("Sheet1").listobjects("table1").databodyrange.rows
  if rng.entirerow.hidden = false then
```

?

Comment: Why not for each row in theListObject.ListRows?

Answer (score 1):

### Populate a List Box With Values From a Discontinuous Range

... that has the same number of columns.

```vb
Sub PopulateWaste()
    
    ' Reference the visible range.
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns("B:C")
        
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the values of each area of the range to an array in a collection.
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    
    Dim arg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    For Each arg In vrg.Areas
       drCount = drCount + arg.Rows.Count ' count the rows
       coll.Add arg.Value ' write
    Next arg
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Loop through the collection and write the values from each array
    ' to the destination array.
    
    Dim sItem, sr As Long, c As Long, dr As Long
    
    For Each sItem In coll
        For sr = 1 To UBound(sItem, 1)
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sItem(sr, c)
            Next c
        Next sr
    Next sItem
        
    Set coll = Nothing
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the list box.
    
    With Me.lbWaste
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = cCount
        .List = dData
        .ColumnWidths = "100;50"
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With

End Sub
```